# tomcat7 server has error filterstart, and does not start

Tags: tomcat, solr, tomcat7, solr4

I am trying to run solr 4.3.0 under tomcat7 in ubuntu 13.04. Please see the log snippet below, which I get when I try to start tomcat by running catalina.sh. I get error filterStart as seen in the log. How do i solve it?

```
sonu@sonu-Vostro-1550:~$ sudo /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:      /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 654 ms
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host- manager.xml
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr4.xml
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not   find a matching property.
**Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/solr4] startup failed due to previous errors**
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5096 ms
^CJun 19, 2013 1:37:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 19, 2013 1:37:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 19, 2013 1:37:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
Jun 19, 2013 1:37:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9999"]
sonu@sonu-Vostro-1550:~$
```

I have changed the default port to 9999 in the server.xml in /etc/tomcat7. I cannot open localhost:9999 or localhost:9999/solr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is related to a change in the logging mechanism within Solr 4.3. From the [Solr Logging](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging) page:

> What changed
>
> These versions do not include any logging jars in the WAR file. They must be provided separately. The Solr example for these versions includes jars (in the jetty lib/ext directory) that set up SLF4J with a binding to the Apache log4j library.
>
> Why did it change?
>
> The logging setup was changed for increased flexibility. With older versions, changing your logging mechanism required either building a special target from the source code or doing surgery on the WAR file. Now anyone can change to another logging mechanism or upgrade to newer component versions simply by changing jar files.

Please see [Using the example logging setup in containers other than Jetty](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging#Using_the_example_logging_setup_in_containers_other_than_Jetty)
for the steps needed to configure Solr Logging to work properly with Tomcat. I had the same issue when I upgraded to Solr 4.3 and this corrected it.

Comment: thanks a lot Paige! i had been banging my head over it for quite sometime...now i can browse to localhost/solr

Answer (score 0):

I am not a TomCat Expert, but i would say your config is faulty for your solr4 servlet

```
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not   find a matching property.
**Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jun 19, 2013 1:35:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/solr4] startup failed due to previous errors**
```

Comment: I uninstalled tomcat7 and installed tomcat6, trying to start it gives Jun 19, 2013 2:32:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded initDirs
SEVERE: Cannot find specified temporary folder at /usr/share/tomcat6/temp
Jun 19, 2013 2:32:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Can't load server.xml from /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/server.xml

Comment: now, i have a server.xml in /etc/tomcat6/, should I just copy this file to /usr/share/tomcat6/con/f? Also do I make the temp folder myself?